# Is it possible to use redisgraph with heroku?

Tags: heroku, redisgraph

I know that it is possible to use redis with Heroku. But what about redisgraph? Does it work as well? If yes, how?

All the best.
Jens

Answer (score 0):

RedisGraph can be deployed in RedisLabs VPC offer see: https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise/vpc/